# What is the maximum size to store data

Tags: iphone, ios4, plist, blob, datastore

I am working an app which stores some large amount of data (hundreds of mbs) in application's own library.
can anyone tell me if there is any size limit for an app to store data?
I also want to know the good method to store  my data.Currently i am using pList to store name of my data files and the actual files are stored under "Document/"..
Should i use Blob  or any other suggestion ..?

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure but you can have a look on it - [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 0):

For saving large amounts of data you should probably look at [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html) or SQLite (a good source is [Mobile Tuts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_store-data/), plist wouldn't be a good choice. And so far I don't really know if there is a limit but if the total amount of data saved in your app is over `500MB` it would be very unresponsive, so maybe you should save it to a server or something.